# Accessing a Microsoft Access database from Ubuntu 14.04 server with Jackcess

Tags: java, ms-access-2010, jackcess

I have installed Jackcess 2.0.4 API on my Ubuntu 14.04 server (IP: 192.168.0.130). And now i want to access a Microsoft Access 2010 DB on a Windows 2003 R2 server (IP: 192.168.0.125).

How do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackcess will need to be able to open the database file, so

1. The database file will need to be in a shared folder on the Windows server, and
2. The Ubuntu server will have to be set up to mount the Windows share, most likely using steps similar to those described here:

[MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

Once that's done, Java code running on the Ubuntu server should be able to use Jackcess to manipulate the Access database file by opening it from the mounted location.

For example, if you've configured the Ubuntu server to make the Windows share available at `/mnt/windowsshare` then Jackcess would simply open the database file in that folder:

```java
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;

// ...

Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("/mnt/windowsshare/Database1.accdb"));
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

Jackcess reads and writes Access database files (.accdb and .mdb files) directly. It does not use the Access Database Engine (ACE/Jet) and does not try to recreate the multi-user support that ACE/Jet provides. Therefore, Jackcess itself has no way of managing multiple concurrent users. (Ref: [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/discussion/456474/thread/295b0032/?limit=50).)

If the Access database resides on a Windows share then there is at least the *possibility* that some other user or process might try to update the database while Jackcess has the file open. If that happens you could very well experience strange errors, or perhaps even corruption of the database file.